# Sonos test suite fails on counting items in new playlist

Tags: sonos

I have a container (music show) with 19 tracks in it and 1 item for recommendations section for this show. So totaly there are 20 items. But if I am adding this show to playlist, only tracks will be processed and playlsit will contain 19 tracks. Sonos controller is working fine with it, but Test Suite fails with checking total items after adding show to playlist with message

> FAIL The seed playlist and newly created playlist should have the same
>   quantity of items inside. (expected 19 != actual 20)

As the result Test Suite fails with 1 error. Is it O.K. to send test suite report with such fail? Or you will deny new service with such fail?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:getMetadataResponse>
            <ns1:getMetadataResult>
                <ns1:index>0</ns1:index>
                <ns1:count>20</ns1:count>
                <ns1:total>20</ns1:total>
                <ns1:mediaCollection>
                    <ns1:id>CONTAINER:RECOMMENDATIONS:594</ns1:id>
                    <ns1:itemType>collection</ns1:itemType>
                    <ns1:displayType>grid</ns1:displayType>
                    <ns1:title>Recommendations</ns1:title>
                    <ns1:canPlay>false</ns1:canPlay>
                    <ns1:canAddToFavorites>false</ns1:canAddToFavorites>
                </ns1:mediaCollection>
                <ns1:mediaMetadata>
                    <ns1:id>TRACK:11422:594</ns1:id>
                    <ns1:itemType>track</ns1:itemType>
                    <ns1:displayType>list</ns1:displayType>
                    <ns1:title>He Ain't Give You None</ns1:title>
                    <ns1:summary>The Radiators</ns1:summary>
                    <ns1:mimeType>audio/mp3</ns1:mimeType>
                    <ns1:trackMetadata>
                        <ns1:artist>The Radiators</ns1:artist>
                        <ns1:duration>531</ns1:duration>
                        <ns1:rating>0</ns1:rating>
                        <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
                        <ns1:canSkip>true</ns1:canSkip>
                    </ns1:trackMetadata>
                </ns1:mediaMetadata>
                <ns1:mediaMetadata>
                    <ns1:id>TRACK:58012:594</ns1:id>
                    <ns1:itemType>track</ns1:itemType>
                    <ns1:displayType>list</ns1:displayType>
                    <ns1:title>Alimony</ns1:title>
                    <ns1:summary>The Radiators</ns1:summary>
                    <ns1:mimeType>audio/mp3</ns1:mimeType>
                    <ns1:trackMetadata>
                        <ns1:artist>The Radiators</ns1:artist>
                        <ns1:duration>632</ns1:duration>
                        <ns1:rating>0</ns1:rating>
                        <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
                        <ns1:canSkip>true</ns1:canSkip>
                    </ns1:trackMetadata>
                </ns1:mediaMetadata>
                [MORE ITEMS HERE]
            </ns1:getMetadataResult>
        </ns1:getMetadataResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am taking some liberties in answering your question since it seems to be directed at Sonos, so apologies in advance. It is very unlikely that your service will be rejected for a bug that happens to be inside Sonos test suite.

So my two cents, go for it and submit your service.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the issue here is that a playlist is defined as container specifically full of track elements (http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/286) and your playlist contains a collection. This is why this is failing to generate the correct count in the test.

Comment: Well, there are container and tracks not in playlist, but in collection, i.e. "Some Crazy Show" will contain container "Recommendations" and list of "Tracks". But when adding this show, server will place in playlist only tracks, without "recommendations" container. But test suite check count after adding show to playlist and he is waiting 19 tracks and 1 container, but that is not right.